# Internet Explorer cannot load image

Tags: image, internet-explorer, jpeg, decode, libpng

i have small problem with (of course) IE. IE cannot load image, but another browser this image can load good. IE is writing to developer console message: Cannot decode image on URL .

Images are static JPG or PNG and his URL is writen in HTML code. Page is local.

Where is a problem?

IE11, in emulation every versions, Windows 8.1 Update 1 64b

```
<img src="img/4.png" />
```

The source code posted (seen in right click > show source code) to browsers is in IE and another same.

I resave this images, and now it function good.

Comment: Code example? Which version of IE? OS?

Comment: You should gather information on the types of images. PNG Index or not? Bits per pixel? JPEG, file format.

Comment: Go to Source of the page and check how it shows in IE and others. can you post it?